# Why are my scheduled Azure notifications not reaching end users on the phone?

Tags: .net, azure, push-notification

I have a problem with getting scheduling notifications reaching phone using Azure notifications hub.
To be clear I am paying for the standard price tire that enables scheduling of notifications.

When I use predefined method from notification hub `ScheduleNotificationAsync()` I can see it in azure metrics in 'Scheduled notification sent' but it doesn't reach end user on the actual phone.

Code:

```
        var notification = new AppleNotification(payload, headers);

        DateTimeOffset currentTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0));

        // Calculate the scheduled time by adding the desired delay (e.g., 1 minute)
        DateTimeOffset scheduledTime = currentTime.AddSeconds(10);

        // Convert the scheduled time back to UTC before scheduling the notification
        DateTimeOffset scheduledTimeUtc = scheduledTime.ToUniversalTime();

        var scheduledNotification = await _pushNotificationsHub.ScheduleNotificationAsync(notification, scheduledTimeUtc, deviceHandle);
```

When I use method `SendDirectNotification()` it works perfectly fine, it gets to the end user.

Comment: A quick google search led me here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer

Answer (score 0):

> I have [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/) ,[git](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet) for  Azure Notification Hubs and Thank  for the commits @brads3290.

[image]

```cs
    var hubClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(connectionString, hubName);
    var notification = new AppleNotification("Your notification payload");
     DateTimeOffset currentTime =     DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0));
     DateTimeOffset scheduledTime = currentTime.AddSeconds(10);
     DateTimeOffset scheduledTimeUtc = scheduledTime.ToUniversalTime();
       var deviceHandle = "device_handle"; 
        try
            {
                var result = await hubClient.ScheduleNotificationAsync(notification, scheduledTimeUtc, deviceHandle);
                Console.WriteLine("Scheduled notification successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error scheduling notification: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Device registration:**

[image]

[image]

- Refer this [Diagnose dropped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer) .
- [NotificationHubClient with FCM push notification all properties not sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583809/notificationhubclient-with-fcm-push-notification-all-properties-not-sent/76588601#76588601)