# NotificationHubClient with FCM push notification all properties not sent

Tags: azure, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I'm working on an inherited project so I'm not sure if I'm missing a config setting or what. I'm sending

```
         {
             NotificationHubClient hub = CreateClient();
             return await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(GetNotificationBody(message, phone, sessionId), userId);
         }
         
         public static Dictionary<string, string> GetNotificationBody(string message, string phone = "", string sessionId = "")
         {
             return new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "message", message }, { "phone", phone }, { "sessionId", sessionId } };
         }
```

when I receive the notification, only `phone` and `message` appear in the data of the FCM.

```
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            string messageText = "";
            if (message.Data.ContainsKey("message"))
                messageText = message.Data["message"];
            string phone = "";
            if (message.Data.ContainsKey("phone"))
                phone = message.Data["phone"];
            string sessionId = "";
            if (message.Data.ContainsKey("sessionId"))
                sessionId = message.Data["sessionId"];
            
// sessionId is empty
   
        }
```

I tested removing the properties, and the message and phone still showed up in the message packet - the values were empty, but the keys were there.

I can't find anything where the body values are set - I thought it was free form. Am I missing something?

Comment: you have to check the template you used on createTemplateRegistration

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are experiencing is likely due to the way FCM handles data payloads. By default, FCM only includes key-value pairs in the data payload if the corresponding values are non-empty. If a value is empty or null, FCM will omit that key-value pair from the data payload. But, even though the key-value pair given correctly as you mentioned the above question is something weird there is no custom config settings needed.

- FCM supports two types of messages one is notification messages and data messages. Notification messages are automatically handled by the FCM SDK, which may modify the payload before delivering it to client app. Data messages, on the other hand, are passed to the app as it is. To get that all custom data is delivered reliably, you should use a data payload.
- Here I created a sample application to test whether the data is notifies or not Firstly I created a new project in Google Firebase and retrieved the server key and register in my azure notification hub.

[image]

- Registered in **Azure notification hub**.

[image]

- I was tested in a sample console app. Below is code which I used.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await SendDataMessageAsync();
    }

    static async Task SendDataMessageAsync()
    {
        // Connection string of your Notification Hub
        string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://wedwfett.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=your-SharedAccessKey=";

        // Notification Hub name
        string hubName = "mynotifyhub";

        // Create Notification Hub client
        var hubClient = new NotificationHubClient(connectionString, hubName);

        // Create FcmNotification with data payload
        var notificationPayload = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "message", "Hello" },
            { "phone", "1234567890" },
            { "sessionId", "ABC123" }
        };

        var payloadJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notificationPayload);
        var notification = new FcmNotification(payloadJson);

        // Send the data message
        await hubClient.SendNotificationAsync(notification);
    }
}
```

- **Azure notification hub metrics:**
  [image]
- Iam able to see the data without missing its properties.
  [image]